# Solidworks PDM API - IEdmBomView.GetRows não retorna os mesmos itens para o BOM que estão no PDM

Tags: c#, solid

Tenho uma rotina em C# que exporta o BOM, mas quando validei, os 2 itens marcados na imagem não são retornados pela rotina GetRows da classe IEdmBomView. Os itens estão normais no Solidworks. E quando faço a exportação da Lista de Materiais para Excel pelo PDM os 2 itens são exportados normalmente.

[image: Configuração]